# Wine Security - Improvement by second user account?

Tags: 11.10, wine, security

Team,

I'm considering installing wine - but still hesitant for security reasons. As far as I found out, malicious code could reach ~/.wine and all my personal data with my user-priviledges - but not farther than that.

So - would it be any safer to create a second user account on my machine and install wine there? That way, the second user would only have reading rights to my files. Is there a way to install wine totally confined to that user - so that I can't execute .exe files from my original account?

PS - I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 64bit if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

You can just change the owner of the wine executable to the second user and then give execute permission only to that user.

Another way would be to move the wine executable to some other place which is not in path of your user account and add it to the path of the other users account.

Third way is, to remove the link in nautilus to execute .exe with wine. But this does not prevent .exe files from ever being executed with this user account.

Fourth way would be to create a .wine directory in your home folder before installing wine and then remove privileges for your user name, such that wine could never access it with your user account.